# How do I send data between two app methods in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Let's say I have an app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});

//From the login.ejs file, a form submitted the values 'email' and 'password'
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    res.redirect("/page")
});

app.get("/page", (req, res) => {
    //Now, here I want to use the email and password from the app.post /login
});
```

Here's the source code of a project I'm working on currently. (If that helps)

The source code is a bit messy and has errors (due to this problem), but anyway, [here it is](https://github.com/arnu515/listr-web-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the data between routes with `query string` or with `session`.

**With Session:** 
Run the below command to install the session lib.

```
$> npm i --save express-session
```

You need to follow the below steps.

1. Create a unique `id` for each user request. (You could use Date().getTime()).
2. Add this unique `id` in the query string.
3. Create a new key with this `id` in session object.
4. Assign the user name and password to the newly created session key.  With this you will able to securely get the `email` and password of each user
5. In `page` route get the `id` from the query string and then retrieve the data from session with this `id` without conflict.

**code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require('express-session'); // add the session lib
const app = express();
// Session secret key
app.use(session({
    'secret': '343ji43j4n3jn4jk3n'
  }))
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});
//From the login.ejs file, a form submitted the values 'email' and 'password'
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    let id = new Date().getTime();
    req.session[id] = { email, password};   
    res.redirect(`/page?id=${id}`)
});
app.get("/page", (req, res) => {
    let id = req.query.id;
    let email = req.session[id].email;
    let password = req.session[id].password
    //Now, here I want to use the email and password from the app.post /login
});
```

**Query String example :**

> Not recommended to add the password in the query string.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});
//From the login.ejs file, a form submitted the values 'email' and 'password'
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    res.redirect(`/page?email=${email}&password=${password}`)
});
app.get("/page", (req, res) => {
    let email = req.query.email;
    let password = req.query.password
    //Now, here I want to use the email and password from the app.post /login
});
```

Comment: I will still not recommend , but if you don't have any other option and you have to pass  then yes this could be used.

Comment: Thanks! It sure works! I'll be sure to hash the password to make it more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible until you are able to safely recognize it's the same person who is making the second call.
The way `res.redirect` works is instructing a browser to make a second call and since all the request handlers are independent of each other, the context is lost. For this demo purpose, you might just use [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session).